# Two GroupBy's on LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

**Aim**:

To return an `IEnumerable` list of `Model`.

**Problem**:

I'm trying to return a list of my model and group on a substring of a field in my database. However I need to group by twice as the first time I group, the substring has occurred yet and therefore isn't actually grouping on anything as the data is unique before the substring.

**Edit**:

I do not need the first group by. I am only including it because this was the query before, I am not sure how to do this query. I need to select the nominal period. Get the first four characters of the Nominal Period. Then do a group by on the new 'Nominal Period'

Example of a Nominal Period - 201304

This is made up of the year and then month. I.e todays nominal period would be 201509.

Therefore whenever I return a Nominal Period with just the first four characters, there will be 12 instances of each nominal period as there are 12 months in the year. This is why I need to do the second group by.

**Model**:

```
 public class YearsModel {
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Model**:

```
 public class ReportingHubViewModel : ReportViewModel {

        public IEnumerable<YearsModel> Years { get; set; }

        public YearsModel YearsModel { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**:

```
model.Years = detailRepo.GetAllYearsFrom(model.ClientID);
```

**Repository**:

```
public class SQLDetailRepository : IDetailRepository {
        ApplicationDbContext camOnlineDb = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public IEnumerable<YearsModel> GetAllYearsFrom(int ClientID) {
            var x = (from d in camOnlineDb.Details
                     where d.ClientID == ClientID
                     where d.NominalPeriod != null

                     select new {
                         d.NominalPeriod
                     });

            return x.GroupBy(r => new { r.NominalPeriod })
                .Select(g => new YearsModel {
                    Year = g.Key.NominalPeriod.ToString().Substring(0, 4)
                })//Need another group by here to group after the substring has occrured 
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Where you're asking to do another `GroupBy` would break the signature of the method. If you did a further `GroupBy` there you wouldn't be returning `IEnumerable<YearsModel>`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: you are selecting only one column in initial query and then you are grouping by that column.why?

Comment: In lambda use ThenBy for second group by example: .GroupBy(r=>r.NominatedPeriod).ThenBy(r=>r.yourProperty)

Comment: @DarkKnight I need to do group on one property: Nominal Period. This is because Nominal Period is made up of the Year(2013) and the Month(02). So a complete Nominal period would be 201406. I need to take the first 4 characters and group on them because there are 12 months in a single year. Therefore there would be 12 instance of Nominal Period which would be exactly the same

Comment: @AndrewKilburn : Do you finallly want list of distinct years? because `x` only has one property which year+month.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want. Thats why I have the substring, just to take the year

Comment: If you want just distinct years, you dont have to use 'GroupBy'

Comment: How can I get the distinct years after the substring has taken place?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn : please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore using `GroupBy` in this case.

One way is to use `Distinct()` like following

```
    return x.Select(y=>.ToString().Substring(0, 4))
            .Distinct()
            .Select(z=>new YearsModel {Year = z})
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I did it a slightly different way. But thank you! I didn't need to use a group by. I really appreciate it